# my image is not get inserted while uploading using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My image  is not get inserted while uploading using codeigniter:

```
function add_newblog()
{
       $sess_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
       $result['query'] = $this->login_model->profile($sess_id);
        foreach($result['query'] as $row)
          {
           $email = $row->blogger_email; 
           $url = $row->blogger_url; 
           $author = $row->blogger_name; 
       if ($this->input->post('submit')) {

        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '0';
        $config['max_width'] = '0';
        $config['max_height'] = '0';

       $this->load->library('upload', $config); 

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $media = 'No Image Uploaded';

        $title = $this->input->post("title");
        $category = $this->input->post('category');
        $content = $this->input->post('content'); 
                $this->blog_model->add_newblog($sess_id,$title,$category,$content,$media,$email,$url,$author);

                $this->session->set_flashdata('valid', 'Blog Created without Image');
                redirect('content_writer/add_blog');
            }
        else {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $data = $this->upload->data();

            $media = $data['file_name'];
            $title = $this->input->post("title");
            $category = $this->input->post('category');
            $content = $this->input->post('content'); 

                $this->blog_model->add_newblog($sess_id,$title,$category,$content,$media,$email,$url,$author);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('valid', 'Blog Created');
                redirect('content_writer/add_blog');
            }

        }
        else{
             $this->session->set_flashdata('invalid', 'Invalid');
                redirect('content_writer/add_blog');
        }
      }
    }
```

The else condition always works. The image name does not get saved in the image path.

Comment: not inserted means not inserted into database or not upload in folder?

Comment: @saty both ...whenever i try to insert an image or media through this upload field (view page query-  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="fileInput">Upload Media</label>
   <div class="controls">                                                                         <input class="input-file uniform_on" name="userfile" id="fileInput" type="file">   </div>  </div>) it always work not uploaded file condition...

Comment: always it shows the value in  $media = no image uploaded

Comment: increse $config['max_size'] = '100';
$config['max_width'] = '200';
$config['max_height'] = '200' and try;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is here in this line

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
```

instead use

```
$config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/<folder name>';
```

OR incase you want to save the image directly in uploads folder just use

```
$config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
```

as well as make your that you form in the veiw section is open with `form_open_multipart()`
hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Set your max_size, max_width and max_height. This would be an example below.

```
$config['max_size'] = '3000';
$config['max_width']  = '1500';
$config['max_height']  = '1500';
```

Comment: I see @salty said it first, sorry

Comment: if you give any suggestion the put a comment not given answer

Comment: I cant, don't have the reputation yet :/ @saty

Comment: @saty, @ David Gilliam,@ karvin.developer ....hey i need to keep the image width and height constant ..if uploaded image is less than the given width and height it does not wanted to insert do any one have suggestions.....

Comment: @Nayanz, sorry I am now seeing this a year later, but did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You havent passed the image name in $this->upload->do_upload() method.

use your

input type='file' name=myDoc

$this->upload->do_upload("myDoc")